# Create VBA that returns search top 5 search results in Google and microsoft edge

Tags: vba, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

[Below is the error I'm getting when entering the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DsWD.png)I'm new to VBA but I'd like to create a macro that returns the top 5 search results of the item listed in cell A15 using either google chrome or microsoft edge? I tried adding in the code below and got an error.

Comment: I updated my question above with the current issue I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

VBA can only automate the **Internet Explorer** browser. So if you want to use google chrome or Microsoft edge then this approach will not work for you.

Below is the sample code that populates Google search results to a worksheet.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetLink()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer

    Dim url As String
    url = "https://google.co.uk/search?q=" + Sheet1.Range("A2").Value
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate url

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Sheet1.Range("B2").Value = .document.querySelector("#search div.r [href*=http]").href
        Sheet1.Range("C2").Value = .document.querySelector("#search div.r [href*=http]").innerText
        .Quit
    End With

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Reference:

[How to get the first search result link of a google search using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53100287/how-to-get-the-first-search-result-link-of-a-google-search-using-vba/53100844)

Below is another helpful thread. Its solution uses the XMLHTTP object.

[Using VBA in Excel to Google Search in IE and return the hyperlink of the first result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495644/using-vba-in-excel-to-google-search-in-ie-and-return-the-hyperlink-of-the-first)

Further, you can try to check the above example and try to modify the sample as per your own requirements.

Comment: Hi- thanks for the update. I tried entering the code and got an error. I dropped a screenshot of the error into my original question above. The error was compile error - user defined type not defined.

Comment: Please go to Tools-> References. Checked the references for 'Microsoft Internet Controls' and 'Microsoft HTML Object Library'. Then after again run the code. See here: https://imgur.com/a/mieHopR